# Remove inheritance from model retaining IDs

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, django-migrations

I have a two classes, one of which inherits from the other

```
class Drink(models.Model):
   ....
```

```
class Juice(Drink)
  ....
```

Now, this was a mistake and I would like to remove the inheritance and have the Juice model to be a normal model `Juice(models.Model)`. Yet, I would like to retain the sequence of `IDs` that are in the superclass. Due to the inheritance, the superclass has an auto ID field and the subclass has a pointer field (`drink_ptr_id`).

What happens now when I just change the syntax is that django tries to add an auto ID field to the juice model and wants me to set a default value. The obvious problem is that I need the sequence of the supermodel to be copied into the auto ID field of the subclass model and I cannot just add a default value. A second problem - which is rather strange to me - is that the subclass already has an auto-incremented ID field, so there is a clash between the newly created field and the old id field.

I tried to follow the advice given in this post: [Remove model inheritance and keep id in newly created autofield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406839/), which is pretty much a similar problem.

But when I follow this advice I get a `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field u'id' in class clashes with ID`. I tried to adapt the manual migration by changing the name if the `ID` to `ID_second` field, but then I got an error that the `ID_second` field is within a primary key which completely messed things up. So after quite a bit of a surgery I am back to where I started. I have quite a lot of data so just starting from scratch is not an option.

Is there a way to remove the inheritance and retaining the foreign keys? If I need to provide more info or explain clearer please LMK. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Change you model.

```
class Juice(models.Model):
    drink_ptr_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

made new shema through makemigrations.

After Makemigrations in new schema should be only `AlterField`, not the AddField or DeleteField.

migrate.

After that you can use your Juice without other Drink. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. I'll try this out asap and report bacl

Comment: So your solution makes sense to me in my mind, but the following happens. Turns out there are two fields: `drink_ptr_id ` and `drink_ptr`. If I add `drink_ptr_id` as above django removes the `drink_ptr` and adds the `drink_ptr_id` which does not work since it asks me for a default value. If I add  the `drink_ptr` as a primary key field, creating the schema works, but running `migrate` gives the error: `Auto-generated field 'drink_ptr' in class 'Juice' for parent_link to base class 'Drink' clashes with declared field of the same name`

Comment: Plus, I think logically I should add the `drink_ptr_id` since the ID should be the primary key.

Comment: i try to check it on test project. I am shure we can find something,